# Importing solution when UAT and Live are not in sync crm2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I use a copy of customer's UAT environment as my Dev. I worked in a solution on top of all other solutions (add existing), however, I come to import into Live (staging), my solution import errors. In UAT, there was a 3rd party managed solution that did not make it to customer’s Live, I only just found out.  So when importing to Live, it first errors about that missing 3rd party managed solution, then when I try to import that 3rd party managed solution, the import errors on some missing components; some of the reported missing components don't even exist in UAT where that solution is meant to have already been installed, and some of the reported missing components exist in both environments, but I customised them in my solution.

What are my options to resolve?

Hypothetically, would importing that 3rd party solution unmanaged instead of managed untangle it?

Why was it managed in UAT in the first place? Does it matter which environment that 3rd party managed solution was created in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of your solution structure. CMIIW, this is from my understanding of your question. You'd have:

**in UAT**
Your custom solution - Unmanaged, 3rd Party Solution - Managed

**in Live**
No solution at all.

I have a question, do you modify anything (form/fields/view) from 3rd party's solution?
And is your client using that 3rd party solution?

This is my opinion to answer your questions:

*What are my options to resolve?*

If that 3rd party solution is not used:
Re-create your solution on fresh CRM deployment, so it will not affect/be affected by any 3rd party solution

If that 3rd party solution used: 
Install 3rd party's managed solution first, then import your custom solution (preferably export as "managed"

*Hypothetically, would importing that 3rd party solution unmanaged instead of managed untangle it?*
AFAIK, you can't import that 3rd party solution as unmanaged unless they give you the unmanaged solution. IMHO, from my experience with CRM 2011, I always try not to have more than 1 unmanaged solution in 1 deployment. And the point of using managed solution is like "released" version of your solution. unless you need the system to change the solution overtime, I reckon it's better to keep it in managed solution.

*Why was it managed in UAT in the first place? Does it matter which environment that 3rd party managed solution was created in the first place?*

The reason it is in UAT in the first place, maybe you can clarify with the client, what are they using that solution for. Maybe they need that solution for their CRM.
AFAIK, it doesn't matter from which environment that 3rd party managed solution was created in the first place. That's their "released" product.

Cheers.